# Linux/C: how to trace the accesses on a number of variables

Tags: linux, gdb, valgrind, trace

I'm trying to profile some existing C code that uses large structs with many members, with the goal of refactoring it into a smaller cache-friendly core struct containing the most frequently-accessed members and a pointer to the colder data.

I want to come up with a way of monitoring the app for a few hours in a few use-cases and produce a report of how often each member in an instance of the struct was accessed.

The x86 debug registers would be ideal, but unfortunately I can only watch 4 addresses simultaneously and I need many more.

I was thinking I could temporarily make each member occupy a whole page of its own, mark all the pages as not-accessible, then set up a segfault handler to record each access before somehow (and this is the tricky bit) recovering and allowing the app to continue. None of the memory being monitored is passed to a syscall, so there wouldn't be any issue with syscalls failing due to unreadable args. Is there a way to use the handler to temporarily make the page accessible, perform the faulting instruction, reprotect the page, then return?

Failing this, is there a more sensible way of recording accesses to many addresses? Something in valgrind maybe? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking I could temporarily make each member occupy a whole page of its own,

This only works for heap-allocated objects, and is what [Electric Fence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence) uses. In the past I've found the Electric Fence overhead so great that it's not usable for anything but toy programs.

> Failing this, is there a more sensible way of recording accesses to many addresses? Something in valgrind maybe?

This is possible by writing a custom Valgrind tool, but that is a complicated proposition.

A better approach may be to use [Pin tool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) instead.

Comment: Thanks, Pin looks awesome! I should have mentioned, I can guarantee all objects will be heap allocated. Presumably Electric fence attempts to track much more of the program data, rather than a small portion of it?

Comment: @gimmeamilk No, efence doesn't track more data -- the overhead of having every allocation go into its own set of pages with a guard page at the end is what kills it (it's 4096x overhead for a 1-byte malloc, less for larger allocations; lots of small allocations are quite typical in real programs).

Comment: That's what I meant - Electric Fence is using a full page for every single malloc by the application, whereas I am only tracking allocations of a specific set of structs.